# No output from Python. Connected to Arduino

Tags: python, python-2.7, arduino, pygame, arduino-uno

May I please know why there is no output on screen for this source code.Also please tell me why and how I can Fix it.

The project is based on this Source Code. [AutoRCCar on GitHub](https://github.com/hamuchiwa/AutoRCCar)

I have flashed my Arduino Uno with this code

```
    // assign pin num
int right_pin = 6;
int left_pin = 7;
int forward_pin = 10;
int reverse_pin = 9;

// duration for output
int time = 50;
// initial command
int command = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(right_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(left_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(forward_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(reverse_pin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  //receive command
  if (Serial.available() > 0){
    command = Serial.read();
  }
  else{
    reset();
  }
   send_command(command,time);
}

void right(int time){
  digitalWrite(right_pin, LOW);
  delay(time);
}

void left(int time){
  digitalWrite(left_pin, LOW);
  delay(time);
}

void forward(int time){
  digitalWrite(forward_pin, LOW);
  delay(time);
}

void reverse(int time){
  digitalWrite(reverse_pin, LOW);
  delay(time);
}

void forward_right(int time){
  digitalWrite(forward_pin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(right_pin, LOW);
  delay(time);
}

void reverse_right(int time){
  digitalWrite(reverse_pin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(right_pin, LOW);
  delay(time);
}

void forward_left(int time){
  digitalWrite(forward_pin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(left_pin, LOW);
  delay(time);
}

void reverse_left(int time){
  digitalWrite(reverse_pin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(left_pin, LOW);
  delay(time);
}

void reset(){
  digitalWrite(right_pin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(left_pin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(forward_pin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(reverse_pin, HIGH);
}

void send_command(int command, int time){
  switch (command){

     //reset command
     case 0: reset(); break;

     // single command
     case 1: forward(time); break;
     case 2: reverse(time); break;
     case 3: right(time); break;
     case 4: left(time); break;

     //combination command
     case 6: forward_right(time); break;
     case 7: forward_left(time); break;
     case 8: reverse_right(time); break;
     case 9: reverse_left(time); break;

     default: Serial.print("Invalid Command\n");
    }
}
```

Then I have run the rc_control_test.py
The Code

```
__author__ = 'zhengwang'

import serial
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


class RCTest(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200, timeout=1)
        self.send_inst = True
        self.steer()

    def steer(self):

        while self.send_inst:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    key_input = pygame.key.get_pressed()

                    # complex orders
                    if key_input[pygame.K_UP] and key_input[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                        print("Forward Right")
                        self.ser.write(chr(6))

                    elif key_input[pygame.K_UP] and key_input[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                        print("Forward Left")
                        self.ser.write(chr(7))

                    elif key_input[pygame.K_DOWN] and key_input[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                        print("Reverse Right")
                        self.ser.write(chr(8))

                    elif key_input[pygame.K_DOWN] and key_input[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                        print("Reverse Left")
                        self.ser.write(chr(9))

                    # simple orders
                    elif key_input[pygame.K_UP]:
                        print("Forward")
                        self.ser.write(chr(1))

                    elif key_input[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                        print("Reverse")
                        self.ser.write(chr(2))

                    elif key_input[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                        print("Right")
                        self.ser.write(chr(3))

                    elif key_input[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                        print("Left")
                        self.ser.write(chr(4))

                    # exit
                    elif key_input[pygame.K_x] or key_input[pygame.K_q]:
                        print 'Exit'
                        self.send_inst = False
                        self.ser.write(chr(0))
                        self.ser.close()
                        break

                elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    self.ser.write(chr(0))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RCTest()
```

But Only have this in Display in the Console

```
RESTART: C:\Users\Raptor_Is_Online\Desktop\AutoRCCar\test\rc_control_test.py
```

If possible please help me.  Any and all questions are welcome.
  I am very new to Python as I'm currently learning C++ but this Project is in Python. How Do I FIX This??

Comment: put more `print()` and mabe you will see where is the problem. Question is how do you run Python code, did you install pygame and SDL1.2 ?

Comment: I ran my code through idle. I pressed Run Module and it opened another idle in which I get the above mention output. Yes I have Pygame but not SDL 1.2.  Also where and what should I print() like what to type in it ? @furas

Comment: first run directly in cmd.exe using `python.exe your_script.py`. Maybe it shows some error message which IDLE coldn't show and it restarts . Later you can put `print()` everywhere - and print values in variables (ie. print("self.ser:", self.ser)`)and messages like `"before pygame.init()"` . This way you can seee when it crash and what values were in variables in this moment. Or learn how to use debugger ;)

Answer (score 0):

use "pygame.display.set_mode()" it will initialize the window click arrow keys on that windows you will get output